Rudin Functional Analysis Problem 7.22.
I am trying to solve question number $22$ from Chapter 7 titled "Fourier Transforms" of Rudin's Functional Analysis which is about Periodic distributions. I am mostly concered about the one-dimensional torus, that is, the circle, so, I will state the question in that particular case.

The space $\mathscr{D} (\mathbb T)$ is the space of all functions
$\varphi$ on $\mathbb T$ such that its periodic extension
$\tilde\varphi$ is in the Frechet space $C^{\infty} (\mathbb R)$. If
$\varphi \in \mathscr D (\mathbb T)$ then for each $N \in \mathbb Z
 _{\ge 0}$, we have that  \begin{equation*} \lVert f \rVert_{N} :=\sum_{k\in \mathbb Z} (1+k^2)^{n} \lvert \hat{\varphi} (k) \rvert
 ^2 < \infty  \end{equation*} where $\hat{\varphi}(k)$ is the $k$th Fourier coefficient of $\varphi$. These norms define a Frechet space
topology on $\mathscr D (\mathbb T)$ which coincides with "usual" one
given by the norms for each $N \in \mathbb Z _{\ge 0}$:
\begin{equation*} \max_{\lvert \alpha \rvert \le N} \sup_{x\in \mathbb
 R} \lvert D^{\alpha} \tilde{\varphi} (x) \rvert \tag{1}\end{equation*}
$\mathscr{D}'(\mathbb T)$ is the space of all continuous linear
functionals on $\scr D$; its member are the distributions on
$\mathbb T$. The Fourier coefficients of any $u \in \mathscr D '
 (\mathbb T)$ are defined by  \begin{equation*} \hat{u} (k) = u(e^{-ik
 (\cdot)}) \qquad (k \in \mathbb Z). \end{equation*}
To each $u \in \mathscr D '$ correspond an $N$ and $C$ such that
\begin{equation} \lvert \hat{u} (k) \rvert \le C (1 + \lvert k
 \rvert)^N \qquad (k \in \mathbb Z). \tag{2} \end{equation}
Conversely if $g$ is a complex function on $\mathbb Z$ that satisfies
$\lvert g (k) \rvert \le C (1+ \lvert k \rvert )^N $ for some $C$ and
some $N$ then $g=\hat{ u}$ for some $u \in \scr D '$.

Here's how I showed that every $u \in \mathscr D'$ satisfies $(2)$. Observe that the norm in Equation $(1)$ is equivalent to the norm $\sum_{\lvert \alpha \rvert \le N} \sup_{x\in \mathbb R} \lvert D^{\alpha} \tilde{\varphi} (x) \rvert$. Now if $u \in \mathscr D'$, there exists $C$ and $N$ such that $|u(\varphi)|\le C \sum_{\lvert \alpha \rvert \le N} \sup_{x\in \mathbb R} \lvert D^{\alpha} \tilde{\varphi} (x) \rvert$ for each $\varphi \in C^{\infty} (\mathbb T)$. If we take $\varphi = e^{-ik (\cdot )}$ then we have $|\hat{u}(k)| \le C (1+ |k| + \ldots + |k|^N) \le C(1+ |k|)^N$.
However I am struggling to show the converse. Any help would be appreciated!

Intuitively, since we want $g$ to be the Fourier transform of $u$ we want to define $u=\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z} g(k)e^{ikx}$. We need to make sure this makes sense:
For $n\geq1$ define $u_n(x)=\sum_{|k|\leq n}g(k)e^{ikx}$. This defines a distribution in $\mathscr D'$. We show that as $n\to\infty$ this converges to a distribution with the desired property. By the Banach-Steinhaus theorem for Frechet spaces it suffices to show that $\langle u_n,\varphi\rangle$ converges for every $\varphi\in\mathscr D$. We have $\langle u_n,\varphi\rangle=\sum_{|k|\leq n}g(k)\langle e^{ikx},\varphi\rangle=\sum_{|k|\leq n}g(k)\hat\varphi(-k)$. From the given bound for $g(k)$ and the fact that the $\hat\varphi(-k)$ are rapidly decreasing we see that this converges as $n\to\infty$. Denote the limit of the $u_n$ by $u$. Then $$\hat u(m)=\langle u,e^{-imx}\rangle=\lim_{n\to\infty}\langle u_n,e^{-imx}\rangle=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{|k|\leq n}g(k)\langle e^{ikx}, e^{-imx}\rangle=g(m).$$
(Note that I assume the Haar measure on $\mathbb T$ to be normalized so that $\mathbb T$ has volume $1$)
